# how to add the subtitles to ggplotly subplots?

Tags: r, ggplotly

Here is just dummy code to reproduce my example:
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
      labs(title = "Iris sepal width vs length", subtitle= "very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long subtitle")


f1<-ggplotly(p1) |> 
       layout(title = list(text = paste0('Iris sepal width vs length',
                           '<br>',
                           '<sup>very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very.</sup>\n',
                           '<sup>very very very very very very very very very very very very very long subtitle</sup>'
                           )))
```

I have two plots (like `p1`). Both have a title and a very long subtite.  I made an interactive subplots using `ggplotly`:

```
 plotly::subplot(
    f1,
    f1,
    nrows = 2,
    heights = c(0.4, 0.6),
    margin = c(0, 0, 0.1, 0),
    titleX = FALSE,
    titleY = FALSE
  )
```

My issue is that subtitle is not displayed for both plots- only for one

[image]

What i was trying to do is to have plot with 2 subplots: each subplot has a title and a long subtitle split in tow lines .  In the example i provided- i did managed to split it in 2 lines- but the gap between the lines is soo huge- that it looks very ugly

Comment: There are a few examples on the Plotly website (depending on what you're looking for). [Check it out.](https://plotly.com/r/subplots/)

Answer (score -1):

To split lines use **"\n"**

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=iris,
             aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                 y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species,
                 shape=Species)) +
  labs(title = "Iris sepal width vs length", 
       subtitle =
         paste0("very \n",
                "very very \n",
                "very very very \n",
                "very very very very \n",
                "very very very very very \n",         # Notice \n at end
                "very very very very very very \n",
                "very very very very very very very \n",
                "very very very very very very very very  \n",
                "long subtitle\n"))
```

Comment: does not work in subplots